# How to delete a full column from spreadsheet using Java?

Tags: java, google-sheets, col

I am building an application by using Google Spreadsheet to store data.
I am adding and updating columns dynamically but not getting how to delete a complete column at once!

Could anyone please help me in deleting a column from spreadsheet? I can delete a cell but want to delete all cells which come under a particular column.

Like delete column 'A' and the nearby column 'B' replace column 'A', Like we do by right clicking on a column and select option 'delete column' on drive spreadsheet.

Can anyone help me doing this? Any api or link?

Comment: This question has been tagged with Google Apps Script, but your subject line states Java. Can you clarify if you are using the Google Sheets API via Java, or the SpreadsheetApp interface in Google Apps Script (a Javascript dialect).

Comment: I am using  Google Sheets API via Java

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [rows and columns operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn) wherein Sheets API allows you to insert, remove and manipulate rows and columns in sheets.

In [deleting rows and columns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns), you may try the sample [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) request wherein second request deletes columns B:D.

The request protocol is shown below:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate


{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 4
        }
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

You may also check [Updating Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#example) guide for more information on how to implement a batch update in different languages using the Google API client libraries including Java.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are correct Teyam, I looked this already but for this I have to add an api calling function by using java.net but I am searching for any such solution which don't require any such type of code.
Does is can't be done like we delete a row using `ListFeed`?